# Tensorflow Serving Git Repository Stale? Tensorflow folder does not exist

Tags: linux, git, docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am attempting to create a Tensorflow server in accordance with the instructions. The `docker build` command works, as does the `docker run` command after it. However, when I attempt to cd into serving/tensorflow it tells me file does not exist. Indeed 'ls' command reveals that the serving directory contains a tensorflow_server directory but no tensorflow directory.

It appears a new Git release was done on Jan 29th 2018 which functionally removed the tensorflow and tf_models submodules from the repository. However, there was not a tandem update of the Tensorflow Serving documentation and tutorials, which now all appear to be stale. The problem I encountered is further described below. My question is how do I get past this problem so that I can run the inception-V3 messaging example in the official tutorial?

**Environment info:**

```
lsb_release -a >>
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

**Some reproducible code:**

Cloned the repo with no apparent problem:

```
:~$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/tensorflow/serving
Cloning into 'serving'...
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Performed `docker build` command, with no apparent problem:

```
~/serving$ docker build --pull -t $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel -f     tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.178MB
Step 1/9 : FROM ubuntu:16.04 ...
Step 6/9 : ENV BAZEL_VERSION 0.5.4 ...
Successfully built 
Successfully tagged ../tensorflow-serving-devel:latest
```

Performed `docker run` command, with no apparent problem:

```
~/serving$ docker run --name=tensorflow_container -it $USER/tensorflow-    serving-devel
root@26f2fg3e417:/#
```

Cloned repo from within Docker container with no apparent problem:

```
root@26f2fg3e417:/# git clone --recursive https://github.com/tensorflow      /serving
Cloning into 'serving'...
remote: Counting objects: 6130, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (91/91), done.
remote: Total 6130 (delta 85), reused 103 (delta 59), pack-reused 5977
Receiving objects: 100% (6130/6130), 2.38 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4358/4358), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Attempt to cd into serving/tensorflow was problematic!:

```
:/# cd serving/tensorflow
bash: root@26f2fg3e417:/#: No such file or directory
```

-ls output:

```
root@...:/# ls
bazel  boot  etc   lib    media  opt   root  sbin     srv  tmp  var
bin    dev   home  lib64  mnt    proc  run   serving  sys  usr
```

cd serving, then ls:

```
/serving# ls
AUTHORS          LICENSE    RELEASE.md  tensorflow_serving
CONTRIBUTING.md  README.md  WORKSPACE   tools
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses. The above suggestion did not work for me.

Fortunately, the following answer by zf109 from GitHub worked:

> you can try manually clone it:
>
> cd /serving && git clone --recursive https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
>
> not sure if that helps but it solves my problem :)

See: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/755

Comment: That would do the same as my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your command was:

```
 git clone --recursive https://github.com/tensorflow      /serving
```

That means the tensorflow repo content is directly in /serving

If you want for `cd serving/tensorflow` to suceed, you need to type instead:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/tensorflow      /serving/tensorflow
```

(make sure you delete first what was cloned in `/serving`)